# Minimum indices from Numpy Array rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Given I have a Numpy array

```
A =[
    [3, 2 ,1],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [8, 7, 9]
   ]
```

Is there a way, I could find the column indices of the minimum element for each row with Numpy functions

```
A = [2, 0, 1]
```

2 is the column for the minimum which is 1 for the row 0

0 is the column for the minimum which is 4 for the row 1

1 is the column for the minimum which is 7 for the row 2

I wanted to know if there is a Numpy way of doing it, without using for loop based approach
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[numpy.argmin](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) should be what you're looking for

Comment: Thank you for helping! I used  ```Index_array = np.argmin(A, axis=-1)``` mentioned in the document, but why is axis = -1?

Comment: I think it's similar to python list negative indexing, which mean -1 in this case should equal to dim=1